# yum update glibc dependency error on SL 6.1

Tags: yum, glibc, scientific-linux

On SL6.1 I am trying to yum update glibc and it's failing I think with a conflict of sources, but I'm not too sure. I don't really know how to parse the yum error, but here it is:

```
# yum update glibc
Setting up Update Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package glibc.x86_64 0:2.12-1.80.el6_3.3 will be updated
---> Package glibc.x86_64 0:2.12-1.80.el6_3.5 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-common = 2.12-1.80.el6_3.5 for package: glibc-2.12-1.80.el6_3.5.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package glibc-common.x86_64 0:2.12-1.80.el6_3.3 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-common = 2.12-1.80.el6_3.3 for package: glibc-2.12-1.80.el6_3.3.i686
---> Package glibc-common.x86_64 0:2.12-1.80.el6_3.5 will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: glibc-2.12-1.80.el6_3.3.i686 (@sl-security)
           Requires: glibc-common = 2.12-1.80.el6_3.3
           Removing: glibc-common-2.12-1.80.el6_3.3.x86_64 (@sl-security)
               glibc-common = 2.12-1.80.el6_3.3
           Updated By: glibc-common-2.12-1.80.el6_3.5.x86_64 (sl-security)
               glibc-common = 2.12-1.80.el6_3.5
           Available: glibc-common-2.12-1.25.el6.x86_64 (sl)
               glibc-common = 2.12-1.25.el6
           Available: glibc-common-2.12-1.47.el6.x86_64 (sl-security)
               glibc-common = 2.12-1.47.el6
           Available: glibc-common-2.12-1.47.el6_2.5.x86_64 (sl-security)
               glibc-common = 2.12-1.47.el6_2.5
           Available: glibc-common-2.12-1.47.el6_2.9.x86_64 (sl-security)
               glibc-common = 2.12-1.47.el6_2.9
```

Any help given is greatly appreciated. The sl and sl-security repositories are not those provided by scientificlinux.org, rather a static mirror with only the relevant packages provided by a research partner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like:

- yum wants to update glibc-common-2.12-1.80.el6_3.**3**.x86_64 to glibc-comon-2.12-1.80.el6_3.**5**.x86_64
- the glibc-common:i686 package needs to stay in lockstep with glibc-common:x86_64
- the latest version of glibc-common:i686 available is glibc-common-2.12-1.80.el6_3.**3**.i686
- hence, it cannot resolve the two

So it appears that glibc-common-2.12-1.80.el6_3.**5**.i686 is missing from the update site. Resolve that and things should be OK.

Comment: Thanks @MikeyB. My solution in the end is to remove glibc.i686 since I don't really need it.

Comment: OK, that works as well! By the way, convention is to upvote and accept my answer if it solved your problem. ;)

Comment: I have accepted your answer assuming it is correct (looks fine, but have not verified), but cannot upvote (reputation).